# Open SubTab in console from Quick Action using Aura or LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, service-cloud-console

I am trying to open Order record page in subtab. I have quick action using lwc wraped in aura which opens as modal. In the modal there is Order link when user clicks it then it should open in subtab. To open the subtab I have to pass parentId. Not sure what to pass here.

I have tried following:

workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().tabId => getting undefined

workspaceAPI.getTabInfo() => getting null,

workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId() => getting false,

Comment: What is your actual requirement? On which page is this LWC present, and whcih record are you trying to open?

Comment: The modal opens from quick action on Asset. I like to open Order record in subtab from either aura or lwc.